# Nice scroll bar not working in safari only

Tags: jquery, css

Nice scroll bar works in chrome, Mozilla, and IE properly  but in safari browser it shows only custom scroll bar, the mouse wheel event not working if i drag and drop custom scroll bar, it work properly. only the mouse wheel scroll not working.